# Dotnet restore failing on azure pipeline due to not being able to load internal nuget feed

Tags: azure-pipelines, nuget, dotnet-restore

My problem is basically that I get an error NU1301: Unable to load the service index for source myPrivateFeedUrl. when running dotnet restore on my pipeline

Yet above, it can match the package source:

```
        Package source mapping matches found for package ID 'myPrivatePackage' are: 'myPrivateFeed'
```

This is happening on a TFS hosted on one of our VMs, also with an azure self hosted agent on another machine

my pipeline yaml

```yaml
pool:
  name: 'pool'

variables:
  solution: '**/*.sln'
  buildPlatform: 'Any CPU'
  buildConfiguration: 'Release'
  

steps:
- task: CmdLine@2
  inputs:
    script: |
      cd $(Agent.BuildDirectory)/s/AppName.App/
      
      dir
      
      dotnet restore --verbosity diagnostic
  env:
      HTTPS_PROXY: "corporate proxy here"
      NO_PROXY: "proxy exceptions here"
- task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
  displayName: 'Build Solution'
  inputs:
    command: 'build'
    projects: '**/project.csproj'
```

my nuget.config

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
    <packageSources>
        <clear />
        <add key="nuget.org" value="https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json" />
        <add key="privateFeed" value="privateFeedUrl" />
    </packageSources>
    <packageSourceMapping>
        <packageSource key="nuget.org">
            <package pattern="*" />
        </packageSource>
        <packageSource key="privateFeed">
            <package pattern="privatePackagePrefix.*" />
        </packageSource>
    </packageSourceMapping>
</configuration>
```

things I've tried:

adding the corporate proxy

adding required certificates to agent machine

disabling:

Limit job authorization scope to current project for non-release pipelines

Limit job authorization scope to current project for release pipelines

running dotnet restore on the agent work folder (it works instantly)

adding nuget authenticate before doing a dotnet restore

same result despite all of that.

Edit:

Permission screen screenshot as requested by one of the comments:

[feed permissions screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qY3AV.png)

Comment: Do you mean `dotnet restore` from local agent, it works fine? Could you please share the screenshot of DevOps `feed setting`->`Permissions` page? Make sure you have `Project Collection build service(org)` added and it has read or contributor role.

Comment: dotnet restore works if ran on powershell on the local agent work directory, not on the pipeline itself.

I will add the requested screenshot in the original post

Comment: The permission looks correct. When you set-up the self-hosted agent, which account did you use? To check the account, you can add a bash task with command `whoami` in pipeline, run to export the user name. If it's different with current one, please re-configure the agent with current account for a check, this is in order to keep consistent with your local env which is working.

Comment: Interesting, i'll look into that. I set it up with the integrated Access, which might be causing issues perhaps? Maybe a PAT would solve it.

Comment: User shows as: OURCOMPANYNAME\BUC-BOD-1$ which is the name of the machine itself. Funny enough I can't sign in via PAT even if I give full access to the token, it will tell me I have no permission to access our devops server.

 NT AUTHORITY\NETWORK SERVICE is the account I used for the setup which was the default.

Comment: You can recreate the PAT, then re-configure the agent, make sure to choose the same user(which is working locally) to set up. Also please check if the network is OK, you can try to access your devops website on browser for a test.

Comment: Ive recreated the PAT about 7 times to no avail unfortunately. It says I have no permissions even though the token says full access. And yes I can access my devops on my browser

Comment: Wired. What if you use another account PAT to register the agent? Will it work?

Comment: may i know if there's any update? Have you created the self-hosted agent successfully with same account?